# Open Blank page in InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am using Ionic 3 and Angular for mobile app development. I am also using the cordova InAppBrowser plugin in my project. I am using Ionic Native to access the in App Browser.

What I want to do is open a blank instance of the InAppBrowser. I don't want any url to load, I want to load a blank page and execute some script on it. Ho can I do this? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use "**about:blank**" I didn’t test the code but it should work.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from "@ionic-native/in-app-browser";

constructor(private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) { }

const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      zoom: 'no'
}

const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create('about:blank', '_self', options);
```